# DDD UI composition across multiple contexts on creation

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-driven

Based on this talk from Mauro Servienti called "All Our Aggregates are Wrong. Here is the link for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkzvQSuYd5I

We might have a few bounded contexts each containing information of a item.

e.g

- Marketing Context - name, description, images
- Sales Context - list price, product code?
- Inventory - stock level

*Each context might have their own name for it, e.g. inventory might call it sales item.*

I think sales might be the owner of an item so when you go to create an item that is the place it will be created.

I have two questions.

**Does the UI call these context's seperately?**

If I have a UI to create a product/item and takes the data for both marketing and sales (list price, product code, name, description), I believe it is the case that the UI will make two separate calls.

The first call being to the sales context to create the item, which will publish a ItemCreated event or similar.
The second call will be to the marketing context to set the name, description, etc...

Is this correct?

**Marketing's item**
so my understanding of the inventory service, is that it will listen for the sales ItemCreated event and then create its own aggregate/stream for its representation of an item (Inventory item)

With marketing on the other hand, if I have a UI where I create the item with sales and then need to set the data in marketing, does the UI wait for an item to be created in marketing before then setting the title and description? Does the UI poll the marketing context until the item has been created and then performs the command to update the data?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in the past.

The best approach I found is:

Firs you have to find the main owner of the item. In my case it was a product catalog.

Having a product in the catalog means the company intent to work with this product even if there is not stock, nor a marketing campaign, nor anything yet. This is an aggregate by its own, its operation (add product to catalog) is completly transactional because even if the event ProductAddedToCatalog fails to be applied in other Bounded Context (BC) (because infrastructure fails) I do not have to undo nor coordinate/orchestate anything. Just retry raising the event. The Catalog BC is kept in a consistent state.

For the others BC; applying the event means they create its entry with empty/default values. i.e. in Warehouse BC the entry is created with 0 stock and its correlated product catalog ID. In marketing the entry is created as a product with no marketing campaings so far. And so on with others BC.

How I modeled the UI taks for this? I created several screens like a wizard.

The first screen ask for product catalgo info. Its only task is insert a new product on the catalog.

The next screen ask for Warehouse info but it is not inserting; it is updating the entry with default values created by applying ProductAddedToCatalog event that was raised in the first step.

This way, in case warehouse step fails, the system keeps its consistent state and a user could use the UI task for updating product stock in Warehouse BC later.

Comment: so I am following but I have a few questions. So you mentioned, that any other BC than the owner should default the data and then update it at after with a command. In Mauro's video, does that mean the name of the item would have been blank/defaulted until set? If the data cant be default should it have been with the owner BC?

Comment: With relation to other BC's listening to the catalog/owner creation even, so they create their own aggregate for product? So e.g. would warehouse listen to ProductAddedToCatalog and create its own Product (or StockProduct) aggregate for the id and any data specific to its BC?
Would this then raise its own event such as StockProductCreated?

Comment: @Matster2 1. You can not compare 1:1 to Mauro example because in the video all related data about products already exist and the shoping cart is a "relation" among those data. 2. Yes to both.

Comment: thank you very much that helps a lot. so in the inventory BC we have a StockProduct Aggregate. Do we have to wait for this to be created (eventually with the event) before we can update it with out information or is it common practise to accept an update in the inventory and not know about a given product id existing? 
How would that work when we have even streams (like in even sourcing) with them begin out of order?
e.g. update stock product stock level (from command), then create stock product (from reacting to product created event)

Comment: @Matster2 Eventual consistency should be a matter of milliseconds; to update the StockProduct Aggregate you have to hydrate it into memory from persistence, that means the StockProduct should exist (in your case, the creation event); if you try to hydrate and does not exist yet I suggest retry policies and in the end throwing a error because something goes wrong. The good thing is that even so, your system has consistency and once the problem is resolved the user can go to Manage Stock UI to update the product.